# Why did this TED speaker use "met" when he probably should have used "meet" instead?

Tags: grammar

In one of the TED talks, *if* *you* *want* *to* *achieve* *your* *goals* *don't* *focus* *on* *them*, speaker Reggie tells us that when he was a 6th grader, he loved his beautiful classmate Lasandra but never had the guts to ask her to be his girlfriend. But he was determined to take action the following year. He says:

> The next year was 7th grade, and at my school, you had a different class every hour, and lockers between classes. For the first hour I had Woodshop. First hour, Lasandra had Home Economics. At my school, you’re allowed to change one class as long as the class you are moving out of **met** at the same time as the class you’re moving in to.
>   So, I walked into the principal’s office and said,“I’d like to change from Woodshop to Home Economics.”

Answer (score 3):

That's a backshift of tense to reflect a so-called *irrealis* situation. With **as long as** he's not describing an actual class that actually met, but a possible scenario, a possible class scheduled for the same time-slot.  **as long as** is a phrase synonymous with **if** and **provided**.

Comment: Still sounds strange with the sentences before and after in present tense

Comment: I agree, sandwiched as it between present-tense verbs. Normally you'd see  a modal **would be allowed if it met** or present tense **are allowed if it meets** or past **were allowed if it met**.  I think the speaker is conflating two patterns.  (substitute **as long as** there for **if**) or conflating two times, past and present.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether "you’re" means "you are" or "you were".

For "you are" – **meets**. For "you were"  – **met**.

Comment: `you are moving out` of is also present